# XCode 13 missing predefined text styles

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode13

Usually there are predefined text styles ( https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/ ) available in storyboard-builder interface. After updating to XCode 13 I no longer have option to select a text style as there is nothing listed.

I tried re-installing but nothing changed.

Does anyone else have this issue? Any ideas?

[image: text style selection]

Comment: Haven't experienced any issues with fonts. Does the issue happen in fresh project (neither `.xcodeproj` nor `.storyboard` are corrupted in some way)?
Try installing [San Francisco fonts](https://developer.apple.com/fonts).

Comment: SF-fonts are installed.

The issue does happen to all iOS-projects with XCode 13. When using Mac-projects I can use text styles normally as I was able to use in XCode 12.5 @ iOS too  ^^

Comment: By _installed_, do you mean you have tried reinstalling 'em?

Comment: If you insist on setting fonts in the Interface Builder, although tedious, I assume you should be able to go around the issue if you describe desired fonts through `.storyboard` source code (e.g., modifying font descriptions of your labels `<fontDescription key="fontDescription" style="UICTFontTextStyleBody"/>`). You can also do it [programmatically in your view classes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/scaling_fonts_automatically).

Comment: Yeah thats not sense of my question as this wouldnt solve my issue. ;) Thanks nonetheless!

Nonetheless, after multiple re-installs incl. deleting derived data, caches etc and reboots I now suddenly showed up text styles correctly again...

Comment: Having the same issue, except it suddenly happened out of nowhere and now I can't get styles to show again. Have been changing text styles the last few days and this morning it just went missing.